# Alias for dictionary operation in Python

Tags: python

I want to do something like this:

```
f[frozenset((1,3,4))] = 5
f[frozenset((1,))] = 3
```

but it's just painful to type these all the time, is there anyway to have alias for this? I know in C++ it's possible to have a helper function which return a reference so you can just type:

```
F(1,3,4) = 5
F(1) = 3
```

with F as a helper function. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that this can really only be achieved via a subclass:

```
class FrozenSetDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self,idx,value):
        try:
            dict.__setitem__(self,frozenset(idx),value)
        except TypeError:
            dict.__setitem__(self,frozenset((idx,)),value)

d = FrozenSetDict()
d[1,2,3] = 4
d[1] = 5
print d
```

yields:

```
{frozenset([1, 2, 3]): 4, frozenset([1]): 5}
```

This introduces an asymmetry between `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` which could easily be fixed by re-defining `__getitem__` in the same way.

This might seem a little messy -- Indeed it is.  Why require a subclass?  That just makes it harder to put non-`frozenset` objects into your dictionary as keys.  You could easily use this recipe though to create a proxy object which will do this with your dict:

```
#I don't like the name of this class -- I'm open to suggestions :)
class FrozenSetProxy(object):
    def __init__(self,obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __setitem__(self,idx,value):
        try:
            self.obj[frozenset(idx)] = value
        except TypeError:
            self.obj[frozenset((idx,))] = value

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        try:
            return self.obj[frozenset(idx)]
        except TypeError:
            return self.obj[frozenset((idx,))]

d = dict()
F = FrozenSetProxy(d)
F[1,2,3] = 4
F[1] = 5
print d
print F[1]
```

Comment: This is a tad overkill, isn't it?

Comment: @mgilson: Excellent, though it would be good to show an example of its usage.

Comment: @delnan -- Sort of.  I don't see any other way to get the syntax that OP is requesting though.

Comment: @mgilson This doesn't yield the syntax OP is asking for either (parens are exhanged for brackets). And I doubt the exact syntax is that important.

Comment: @delnan -- That's true.  To get it with parens you'd override `__call__` instead...

Comment: @mgilson `__call__` doesn't help, it's simply impossible. Even if you override `__call__`, OP's code doesn't even run. Call followed by an assignment operator is a syntax error, period. `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Comment: @delnan -- Right.  Don't know what I was thinking with that comment (clearly I wasn't).  You're obviously correct about that portion of this conversion (at least -- Maybe the rest of it too :-P)

Comment: @ChaoxuTong -- I'm not sure that I understand what you're saying about writing a for-loop ...

Comment: @mgilson like for i in f: do something, to make this happen, I need to implement iterator for this data structure.

Comment: But @mgilson's solution still allows you to do the normal `dict` things. `for (k,v) in d.items():
    print k, v`

Comment: @ChaoxuTong -- Since you're subclassing `dict`, you can iterate over it as you always have ...

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing like a C++ reference in Python, and the syntax you use is illegal to boot (in the words of the parser: `can't assign to function call`). You *could* emulate it with an object or subclass `dict` to customize its `__getitem__`. But there's a simpler and less intrusive way: Pass the value to the helper too, and let it handle the assignment:

```
def blah(f):
    def F(*args, value):
        f[frozenset(args)] = value
    F(1, 3, 4, value=5)
    F(1, value=3)
```

Note that this uses a Python 3 feature, keyword-only parameters. If you need it to work with Python 2, you can emulate the call syntax by accepting `**kwdargs`:

```
def F(*args, **kwds):
    # optional: check that no other keyword arguments were passed
    f[frozenset(args)] = kwds['value']
```